# Fast create configurable product in magento

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I was trying to add a configurable product in Magento backend. I spent 30 minutes to create a product with 5 sub-products.
How can I add products most fast? I need advice Which extension I can use?

Comment: I would strongly urge you to check out Magmi:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are new to all these.So i will try to go in detail.

1. First you create a configurable product,i think you don't have problem creating it.Until now you cannot add the associated product.
2. First save the product click **Save and Continue**
3. Now on the left you see the tab named **Associated Products** click on that You will see a form **Quick simple product creation**.Here you can weight,status,qty etc and click **Quick Create** button.

Thats it you just quickly create one simple product.In this way you can create others.
Below is the screenshot related to above description.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You create the first "configurable product" and thats is your main product. If you go to that product you can create very fast some new sub products.

Go to "Associated Products" on the left. There you can generate some new products with the defined values. Its very fast. So normally you don't need an extension for that.